# Is it possible to create a task continuation of the same generic type as its predecessor?

Tags: c#

```
    [Test]
    public void TaskContinuationIsNotOfTheSameGenericType()
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => new Box{Name = "bar"});

        var async = t as Task;

        var nt = async.ContinueWith(n =>
        {
            dynamic tmp = n;
            return tmp.Result;
        });

        nt.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine(nt.Result);
        Console.WriteLine(nt.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName);
    }

    public class Box
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

Outputs:

```
bar
System.Object
TestingStuff.Tasks.Continuations+Box
```

Is it possible to create a task continuation of the same type as the base type? For example: if the base type is "Task of int" , is it possible to generically create a continuation of the base type which is also "Task of int"?

Note:

The code above is just an example, I don't know the specific generic type of the base task.

Comment: Do you mean something like how `public Task<T> ReportAndContinue<T>(Task<T> task) { return task.ContinueWith(t => { T result = t.Result; Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()); return result; }); }` would return a task of the same sort as that passed into it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: As a wrote in the note: I don't know the specific generic type of the initial task, it is passed as Task not Task<T>.

Comment: Oh. I understand now. You could call a method like that in my previous comment through reflection perhaps, is the only way I can think of right now.